# client side IDs of share point elements

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery, client

I need to hide some menu items that come OOTB on sharepoint pages. I can do this through javascript/jquery, but am not sure how consistent are the client side IDs of various elements on SP pages. I dont want my code to break if MS decides to name them differently in the future.

Thanks

Comment: Thre are usually more robust ways to select the elements beside ID, what specific menu items are you talking about (so we can make an example)?

Comment: @erikb this is for a custom list based on content types. I don't want users to add just any default item, instead they need to select a specific content type. I am trying to remove the href from the NEW menu items as shown below so that the users dont add any default item to the list by accident.

[link](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=c28a8d8)

Comment: So the user must make a choice? Or is the problem the content type that comes with the list? - if so you could just remove this CT from the list. First guess at selector could be something like `.ms-list-addnew a:has(span)`, or the first `a`

Answer (score 0):

Definetly we should not use 'id' or 'Class' for manipulating the elements. Instead we can use 'Title' for instance. Below is the example code to use.

For Example i have select tag with the Title as Cars, i can get the value selected on the basis of  Title name, instead of using its 'id' or 'class'

```
<select id ="wp123123select" Title="Cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

In order to get the option selected value using JQuery,

```
var optSelect = $("select[title='Cars'] option:selected").text();
```

OR We can find the element using 'nobr'. Below is the example.

```
var strDesc = "Your Description goes here";
$("nobr:contains('Project Description')").closest('td').next().find('textarea').text(strDesc);
```

@Aamir, Could you please post the HTML, so that i can refine my answer..!!

Comment: To your quite generic answer I would like to point out that `title` attribute in SharePoint is very very often based on language, and so nothing I would recommend anyone to use.

Comment: @Nishkalank I have noticed that there are more than one item on the page having the same title.